# The Method of Image Charges

Tags: electrostatics, method-of-images

I'm learning advanced electromagnetism these days. Can anyone please explain what is and how to use the method of image charges? If you can also provide an example, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The method of image charges is a calculational trick that can be used to evaluate the electric field of a charge near a conductor in certain high-symmetry situations. They hinge on the fact that the electric fields in a region are fixed if you know (1) the location of charges in the region and (2) the potential at the boundary of the region. The method of images reasons like so: it can be quite difficult to evaluate the charge distribution that forms on a conductor close to a charge, but we know the conductor is an equipotential surface. By adding a "false" charge outside of the region of interest that creates the same equipotential surface, and removing the conductor, we end up with the same field configuration.

I do not have time to work out a whole problem here, but here is an example in words: suppose a single point charge $Q$ is placed above an infinite grounded conducting plane, say at location $(0, 0, z)$ where the conductor is in the $xy$-plane. We can get the same potential on the $(x, y, 0)$ plane by removing the conductor and adding a charge of value $-Q$ at $(0, 0 , -z)$. Then the field for all $(x, y, z)$ with $z > 0$ can be found simply by adding the fields produced by the two point charges. Since, in this region, the boundary conditions and charge distribution is the same as the case with the conductor, the answers must match.

Note that the method of image charges is limited in a few ways. First, one has to get somewhat lucky with the conductor arrangements -- really there are only a few specific geometries where it works cleanly, which are the ones you'll find in textbooks. Second, note that anywhere outside the region where you have "mocked" the correct boundary conditions, the method of image charges does not apply. In our example, for instance, all the $(x, y, z)$ points with $z < 0$ do *not* have fields given by the pair of point charges.